# JDialog with transparent background which blurs things underneath

Tags: java, swing, background, blur, jdialog

I'm trying to make a transparent JDialog, which blures what´s underneath it (for better readability). Already found this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html), but there the contents of the dialog are blurred. Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167814/jframe-with-blurred-transparent-background), but there everything (things underneath and contents of the Dialog) is blured and it's flickering.

Here's a screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

The top is what I already have and the bottom what I want to achieve.

Comment: Even if you are not allowed to embed images, you should post your image on i.stack.imgur.com.  Links to other external sites have a tendency to go stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it appears to be pretty tricky to get something like what you want to achieve. I ended up using a JLayeredPane which contains one layer for the blurred background and one for the actual content.

I am not entirely happy with the result but I didn't find a better solution now.
The problem is that Java does not provide a proper way to capture things behind the actual application which leads to the need of hiding the content before taking the screenshot. That also is the problem which causes the flickering you mentioned.
To avoid this I do only reaint the background if the application gets resized or moved. There should be put some more effort into this once really used, e.g. if the app gets minimized. But since this example cannot be resized ord minimized it's not really important right now.
The downside of this approach however is that it's completely ignoring whether or not the Background isn't static. If you use the application in front of a video for example, the current version does not change the background based on the videos current frame. This may be possible if you uncomment the Timer in my examples *setVisible(...)* but then we get the flickering back.

I'd suggest you to think about using JavaFx. Since CSS already provides a blur-functionality it may work for Fx as well. But since I didn't try that yet I cannot assure you it's working.

Long story short, here's the example. The blurring function is used from your link above.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlurryFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ComponentListener {

    public static void main(String... sss) {

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("TestLabel 1");
        label1.setSize(500, 100);
        label1.setForeground(Color.RED);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TestLabel 2");
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.setOpaque(false);
        testPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        testPanel.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        testPanel.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        BlurryFrame frame = new BlurryFrame(800, 600, testPanel);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final BackgroundPanel backgroundPane;
    private final JLayeredPane container;
    private final JPanel containerPane;
    private final Robot robot;

    // This rectangle is going to be your screenshots bounds to keep the image only as big as necessary
    private final Rectangle captureRect;

    // This is going to be the blurred screenshot
    private BufferedImage background;

    public BlurryFrame() {
        this(1280, 800);
    }

    public BlurryFrame(int width, int height) {
        this(width, height, null);
    }

    public BlurryFrame(int width, int height, JComponent component) {

        this.captureRect = new Rectangle();
        try {
            this.robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        this.backgroundPane = new BackgroundPanel();
        this.backgroundPane.setOpaque(false);
        this.backgroundPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        this.backgroundPane.addComponentListener(this);

        this.containerPane = new JPanel();
        this.containerPane.setOpaque(false);
        this.containerPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.containerPane.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.container = new JLayeredPane();
        this.container.setOpaque(false);
        this.container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.container.add(this.backgroundPane, 1);
        this.container.add(this.containerPane, 0);

        this.getContentPane().add(this.container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void add(JComponent component) {
        this.containerPane.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.containerPane.repaint();
    }

    // This method does not really do much but ultimately triggers the screenshot by ending up in #componentHidden(...)
    private void capture() {
        this.containerPane.setVisible(false);
        this.backgroundPane.setVisible(false);
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {

        super.setVisible(visible);
        this.capture();

        // XXX uncomment this if you want to see the flickering
        // Timer timer = new Timer(60, this);
        // timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {

        super.setSize(width, height);

        this.captureRect.setSize(width, height);
        this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        if (this.isVisible())
            this.capture();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension dimension) {

        super.setSize(dimension);

        this.captureRect.setSize(dimension);
        this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
        this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);

        if (this.isVisible())
            this.capture();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPreferredSize(Dimension dimension) {

        super.setPreferredSize(dimension);

        this.captureRect.setSize(dimension);
        this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
        this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);

        if (this.isVisible())
            this.capture();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.capture();
    }

    int i = 0;

    // This is where the magic happens. The capturing needs to be done here in order to assure the applications content has really been hidden
    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

        int x = this.getLocationOnScreen().x;
        int y = this.getLocationOnScreen().y;

        this.captureRect.setLocation(x, y);

        this.background = this.robot.createScreenCapture(this.captureRect);

        //XXX uncomment this if you want to see what gets captured
        //      if (this.i < 1) {
        //          try {
        //              ImageIO.write(this.background, "png", new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\test.png"));
        //          } catch (IOException ex) {
        //              ex.printStackTrace();
        //          }
        //          this.i++;
        //      }

        this.containerPane.setVisible(true);
        this.backgroundPane.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        this.capture();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        this.capture();
    }

    private class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

        private final float[] matrix = {
                0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f,
                0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f,
                0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f,
        };

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (BlurryFrame.this.background != null) {

                BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, this.matrix));
                BufferedImage blurryBack = op.filter(BlurryFrame.this.background, null);

                g.drawImage(blurryBack, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I marked BenGe89s answer as accepted, cause it solves my problem.

However I wanted to share my extensions to make the frame moveable. I used this [ComponentMover](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=HTML-Encrypter-master/ComponentMover.java) and modified it a bit, so the frame get's notified when the dragging starts and stops. While the frame is moved the background will be just transparent to avoid flickering.

```
package de.win;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComponentMover extends MouseAdapter {
// private boolean moveWindow;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Class destinationClass;
private DragNotifier dragNotifier;
private Component destinationComponent;
private Component destination;
private Component source;

private boolean changeCursor = true;

private Point pressed;
private Point location;

private Cursor originalCursor;
private boolean autoscrolls;

private Insets dragInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
private Dimension snapSize = new Dimension(1, 1);

/**
 * * Constructor for moving individual components. The components must be regisetered using the registerComponent() method.
 */
public ComponentMover() {
}

/**
 * * Constructor to specify a Class of Component that will be moved when drag events are generated on a registered child component. The events will be passed to the first ancestor of this specified class.
 * 
 * @param destinationClass
 *            the Class of the ancestor component
 * @param component
 *            the Components to be registered for forwarding drag events to the ancestor Component.
 */
public ComponentMover(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class destinationClass, DragNotifier dragNotifier, Component... components) {
    this.destinationClass = destinationClass;
    this.dragNotifier = dragNotifier;
    registerComponent(components);
}

/**
 * * Constructor to specify a parent component that will be moved when drag events are generated on a registered child component.
 * 
 * @param destinationComponent
 *            the component drage events should be forwareded to
 * @param components
 *            the Components to be registered for forwarding drag events to the parent component to be moved
 */
public ComponentMover(Component destinationComponent, DragNotifier dragNotifier, Component... components) {
    this.destinationComponent = destinationComponent;
    this.dragNotifier = dragNotifier;
    registerComponent(components);
}

/**
 * * Get the change cursor property
 * 
 * @return the change cursor property
 */
public boolean isChangeCursor() {
    return changeCursor;
}

/**
 * * Set the change cursor property
 * 
 * @param changeCursor
 *            when true the cursor will be changed to the Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR while the mouse is pressed
 */
public void setChangeCursor(boolean changeCursor) {
    this.changeCursor = changeCursor;
}

/**
 * * Get the drag insets
 * 
 * @return the drag insets
 */
public Insets getDragInsets() {
    return dragInsets;
}

/**
 * * Set the drag insets. The insets specify an area where mouseDragged events should be ignored and therefore the component will not be moved. This will prevent these events from being confused with a MouseMotionListener that supports component resizing.
 * 
 * @param dragInsets
 */
public void setDragInsets(Insets dragInsets) {
    this.dragInsets = dragInsets;
}

/**
 * * Remove listeners from the specified component
 * 
 * @param component
 *            the component the listeners are removed from
 */
public void deregisterComponent(Component... components) {
    for (Component component : components)
        component.removeMouseListener(this);
}

/**
 * * Add the required listeners to the specified component
 * 
 * @param component
 *            the component the listeners are added to
 */
public void registerComponent(Component... components) {
    for (Component component : components)
        component.addMouseListener(this);
}

/**
 * * Get the snap size
 * 
 * @return the snap size
 */
public Dimension getSnapSize() {
    return snapSize;
}

/**
 * * Set the snap size. Forces the component to be snapped to the closest grid position. Snapping will occur when the mouse is dragged half way.
 */
public void setSnapSize(Dimension snapSize) {
    this.snapSize = snapSize;
}

/**
 * * Setup the variables used to control the moving of the component:
 * 
 * source - the source component of the mouse event destination - the component that will ultimately be moved pressed - the Point where the mouse was pressed in the destination component coordinates.
 */
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    dragNotifier.dragStart();

    source = e.getComponent();
    int width = source.getSize().width - dragInsets.left - dragInsets.right;
    int height = source.getSize().height - dragInsets.top - dragInsets.bottom;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(dragInsets.left, dragInsets.top, width, height);

    if (r.contains(e.getPoint()))
        setupForDragging(e);
}

private void setupForDragging(MouseEvent e) {
    source.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    // Determine the component that will ultimately be moved

    if (destinationComponent != null) {
        destination = destinationComponent;
    } else if (destinationClass == null) {
        destination = source;
    } else // forward events to destination component
    {
        destination = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(destinationClass, source);
    }

    pressed = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    location = destination.getLocation();

    if (changeCursor) {
        originalCursor = source.getCursor();
        source.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }

    // Making sure autoscrolls is false will allow for smoother dragging of individual components

    if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) destination;
        autoscrolls = jc.getAutoscrolls();
        jc.setAutoscrolls(false);
    }
}

/**
 * * Move the component to its new location. The dragged Point must be in the destination coordinates.
 */
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point dragged = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    int dragX = getDragDistance(dragged.x, pressed.x, snapSize.width);
    int dragY = getDragDistance(dragged.y, pressed.y, snapSize.height);
    destination.setLocation(location.x + dragX, location.y + dragY);
}

/*
 * * Determine how far the mouse has moved from where dragging started (Assume drag direction is down and right for positive drag distance)
 */
private int getDragDistance(int larger, int smaller, int snapSize) {
    int halfway = snapSize / 2;
    int drag = larger - smaller;
    drag += (drag < 0) ? -halfway : halfway;
    drag = (drag / snapSize) * snapSize;

    return drag;
}

/**
 * * Restore the original state of the Component
 */
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    source.removeMouseMotionListener(this);

    if (changeCursor)
        source.setCursor(originalCursor);

    if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent) destination).setAutoscrolls(autoscrolls);
    }

    if (dragNotifier != null) {
        dragNotifier.dragComplete();
    }

}

interface DragNotifier {
    public void dragComplete();

    public void dragStart();
}

}
```

Modified BlurryFrame:

```
package de.win;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import de.win.ComponentMover.DragNotifier;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlurryFrame extends JDialog implements ActionListener,     ComponentListener, DragNotifier {

public static void main(String... sss) {

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("TestLabel 1");
    label1.setSize(500, 100);
    label1.setForeground(Color.RED);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TestLabel 2");
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.setOpaque(false);
    testPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    testPanel.add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    testPanel.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    BlurryFrame frame = new BlurryFrame(800, 600, testPanel);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new ComponentMover(frame, frame, testPanel);
}

private final BackgroundPanel backgroundPane;
private final JLayeredPane container;
private final JPanel containerPane;
private final Robot robot;

// This rectangle is going to be your screenshots bounds to keep the image only as big as necessary
private final Rectangle captureRect;

// This is going to be the blurred screenshot
private BufferedImage background;

public BlurryFrame() {
    this(1280, 800);
}

public BlurryFrame(int width, int height) {
    this(width, height, null);
}

public BlurryFrame(int width, int height, JComponent component) {

    this.captureRect = new Rectangle();
    try {
        this.robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    this.backgroundPane = new BackgroundPanel();
    this.backgroundPane.setOpaque(false);
    this.backgroundPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    this.backgroundPane.addComponentListener(this);

    this.containerPane = new JPanel();
    this.containerPane.setOpaque(false);
    this.containerPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.containerPane.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    this.container = new JLayeredPane();
    this.container.setOpaque(false);
    this.container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.container.add(this.backgroundPane, 1);
    this.container.add(this.containerPane, 0);

    this.getContentPane().add(this.container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void add(JComponent component) {
    this.containerPane.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.containerPane.repaint();
}

// This method does not really do much but ultimately triggers the screenshot by ending up in #componentHidden(...)
private void capture() {
    this.containerPane.setVisible(false);
    this.backgroundPane.setVisible(false);
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {

    super.setVisible(visible);
    this.capture();

    // XXX uncomment this if you want to see the flickering
    // Timer timer = new Timer(60, this);
    // timer.start();
}

@Override
public void setSize(int width, int height) {

    super.setSize(width, height);

    this.captureRect.setSize(width, height);
    this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

    if (this.isVisible())
        this.capture();
}

@Override
public void setSize(Dimension dimension) {

    super.setSize(dimension);

    this.captureRect.setSize(dimension);
    this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
    this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);

    if (this.isVisible())
        this.capture();
}

@Override
public void setPreferredSize(Dimension dimension) {

    super.setPreferredSize(dimension);

    this.captureRect.setSize(dimension);
    this.backgroundPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
    this.containerPane.setBounds(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);

    if (this.isVisible())
        this.capture();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.capture();
}

int i = 0;

// This is where the magic happens. The capturing needs to be done here in order to assure the applications content has really been hidden
@Override
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

    int x = this.getLocationOnScreen().x;
    int y = this.getLocationOnScreen().y;

    this.captureRect.setLocation(x, y);

    this.background = this.robot.createScreenCapture(this.captureRect);

    // XXX uncomment this if you want to see what gets captured
    // if (this.i < 1) {
    // try {
    // ImageIO.write(this.background, "png", new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\test.png"));
    // } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ex.printStackTrace();
    // }
    // this.i++;
    // }

    this.containerPane.setVisible(true);
    this.backgroundPane.setVisible(true);
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    this.capture();
}

@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    this.capture();
}

private class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    private final float[] matrix = { 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (BlurryFrame.this.background != null) {

            BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, this.matrix));
            BufferedImage blurryBack = op.filter(BlurryFrame.this.background, null);

            g.drawImage(blurryBack, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void dragComplete() {
    this.capture();
}

@Override
public void dragStart() {
    this.background = null;
    this.backgroundPane.repaint();
}
```

}